# What Field of Probability Deals With The Following

Tags: statistics

Say there is this hypothetical lottery. A ticket is USD 1.00; the chance of winning is 1 in 100,000,000,000,000,000; but the prize is more than  USD 100,000,000,000,000,000. (For he sake of this argument, please ignore things such as “there is no such amount of money in this world,” etc.) Mathematically, I should buy a ticket; on the other hand, any rational person would know that is an awfully-wasted one dollar. What field of statistics, probability, or science, deals with such things?

(First I thought it could be Subjective Probability, but I think not.)

Comment: You might be interested in [Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). So yes, it's probability.

Comment: An even more extreme version of what you're talking about is called the [St. Petersburg Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox); you can see on that page some possible resolutions to reconcile the difference between "classically rational" and "pragmatically rational".

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is "utility function" which is a common concept in probability theory/mathematical economy/actuarial sciences. The probability is not subjective, but the utility of the outcome is. In probability theory the utility function is tacitly ignored since probability theory is about objective probabilities, not about what decision should one make based on any particular probability (though some texts do mention it). In mathematical economy and actuarial sciences the concept of utility function is fundamental. For instance, the whole basis of insurance is that most people are risk-evasive, which is modeled mathematically by having a concave utility function.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a (not too technical) textbook specifically on this topic?

Comment: There are plenty of books on mathematical economy/actuarial sciences. Actuarial sciences is probably more likely to be less technical than mathematical economy.